# iOS7 UIImagePickerController cancel button disappear

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, ios7

The Cancel button is miss?! How can I fix this? Thank you very much.

```
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
    {
        if(buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            self.ctr = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            self.ctr.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            self.ctr.delegate = self;
            self.ctr.allowsEditing = YES;
            [self presentModalViewController:self.ctr animated:YES];
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Try to subclass UIImagePickerController then inside your subclass - (void)viewDidLoad, add a cancel button.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I also have the same issue and tried many ways. However, it cannot be shown still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the UIImagePickerController navigationBar.tintColor, it should be OK.

```
self.ctr.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];//Cancel button text color
[self.ctr.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor blackColor]}];// title color
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @jxdwinter Having same issue but for UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera. I have added your code but no use. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like apple made some mistake with it (iOS 10, Xcode 8) because just changing tint color of UIImagePickerController could not be done, cause, before controller isn't have `topItem` property, or `navigationController` property. So have done the changes in `UIImagePickerController extension`. But I checked `navigationController` and `topItem` in those overrided methods: `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`. but it still was `nil`. So i decide to check it in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, and voila! It's wasn't nil, so we can set bar tint color of exact rightBarButtomItem here!

Here is example:

```
    extension UIImagePickerController {
        open override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
            self.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.black 
            self.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

[image: Exampel on simulator (but it tested on )]

And don't forget to call `super.viewWillLayoutSubviews`, it's very important ;-)
EDIT: But it still has problems when return to the albums screen..

Answer (score 0):

Change the tintColor

```
self.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.black
```

If that doesn't work run through your view controllers to see if there isn't a place where you changed the appearance of the navigation bar and reset the change.