# In UIImagePickerController Cancel button not showing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

here i m using below code. please help me if anybody know this issue.
and i tried below urls also, but its not working. please help me

[iOS7 UIImagePickerController cancel button disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941582/ios7-uiimagepickercontroller-cancel-button-disappear)
[UIImagePickerController inside UIPopoverController doesn't show Cancel button on iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922471/uiimagepickercontroller-inside-uipopovercontroller-doesnt-show-cancel-button-on?noredirect=1#comment42393741_26922471)

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
picker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
picker.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

My Issue:
[image]

My Req:
[image]

Comment: Do you use `appearance` category for `UINavigationBar` in your app? Or any other?

Comment: @Venkatesh: Please check the answer provided by users and up vote for best answer. also accepts some one's answer if your problem got solved by using the answer

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this

Comment: Please refer this answer if every case doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/a/50490924/1201274

Answer (score 8):

This is what worked for me:

```
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: {
        imagePicker.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .black
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like apple made some mistake with it (iOS 10, Xcode 8) because just changing tint color of UIImagePickerController could not be done, cause, before controller isn't have `topItem` property, or `navigationController` property. So have done the changes in `UIImagePickerController extension`. But I checked `navigationController` and `topItem` in those overrided methods: `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`. but it still was `nil`. So i decide to check it in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, and voila! It's wasn't nil, so we can set bar tint color of exact rightBarButtomItem here!

Here is example:

```
    extension UIImagePickerController {
        open override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
            self.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.black 
            self.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

[image: Exampel on simulator (but it tested on )]

And don't forget to call `super.viewWillLayoutSubviews`, it's very important ;-)
EDIT: But it still has problems when return to the albums screen..

Comment: This helped me to get cancel button. But now in camera roll not able to find bar button items. Please guide me if u find solution means. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

If every effort doesn't work then you must have to use appearance() method. So try to write following lines in any view controller(UIImagePickerController) which you want to present. You can use appearance in any class but you may have used UIBarButtonItem.appearance() for some other purposes so find that and write that code in viewDidDisappear().

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for: .normal)
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for: .highlighted)
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Swift 4.2 Solution**, Add below code into AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIImagePickerController.self]).tintColor = .black
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not embedded viewController to Navigation Controller

**Please do that and try the code: (Objective - c)**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];  
}    

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
        UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        }];

    UIImageView *imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 300)];
    imageview.image=image;
}
```

Comment: Embed your view controller to navigation controller from storyboard

Answer (score 1):

I used the same code that you posted. Its showing the "cancel" button.

```
 UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    picker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    picker.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

May be you are using any custom navigation bar and you set the property for app delegate to changing the tint color of navigation nar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like update some of item properties make the button visible, so... just turn it enabled like that:

```
present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: {
    self.imagePicker.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If any of the above does not work out for you,
try adding this when you define your `UIImagePickerController`

```
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .popover // Or.fullScreen (Can also check cases for iPad and iPhone as per requirement)
```

Worked for me like a charm. Was quite bugged up by this

Comment: Thanks, setting modalPresentationStyle to .fullscreen worked for me.

Comment: if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIDocumentBrowserViewController.self]).tintColor = nil
            UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIImagePickerController.self]).tintColor = nil
        }

Try adding this in your app delegate.
I find it really useful. You won't need the above i guess after this.
let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Subclass UIPickerViewController as below:

```
class CustomImagePicker: UIImagePickerController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.black
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.init(red: 0.0, green: 122.0/255.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)], for: .normal)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white // your color
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(nil, for: .normal)
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    }

}
```

And use As:

```
func openGallary()
    {
        picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
        picker!.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
        self.present(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5:

```
  imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

Answer (score 0):

change the UIImagePickerController navigationBar.tintColor
try this code :

```
UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];
    [bar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImagePickerController *imgPicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];    
imgPicker.delegate = self;
imgPicker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
UIImagePickerControllerSourceType sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;

if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: sourceType])
{
    imgPicker.sourceType=sourceType;
    [self presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
let BarButtonItemAppearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()

BarButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: .blue), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have face this kind of same issue and after wasting lot of time i found solution. I have customise navigation bar appearance like below code that why this issue was happened.

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "ic_left")
    let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "FuturaPT-Medium", size: 16)!]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attributes
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "line.png"),for: .bottom,barMetrics: .default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage(named: "line.png")
```

> UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:
>   UIColor.clear], for: .normal)

This is just custom appearance of navigation bar we just need to change last line of code because i have set title color to clear. This is really very simple. Put this code before presenting your image picker controller.

> UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:
>   UIColor.black], for: .normal)

And again if you don't want navigation bar button title make text color to clear.
**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code for  swift 3 or above

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()

picker.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this Code:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And add delegate Method: `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
  [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
  }];

  self.img = image;
  [self.iconBtn setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: me too done same process, wen u pick any image from gallery @ that time this method called didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo, but my prob is before picking the image "cancel button " not display

Answer (score -1):

i think this will help you.Just paste the code inside imagePickerControllerDidCancel then dismiss it (Swift 4).

```
picker.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
```